# Software for measuring internet traffic?

Tags: windows-7, networking, internet

I'm interested in finding a free piece of software for Windows XP & 7 that allows us to measure both incoming and outgoing internet traffic, but not traffic between users of the local network.

I live in a shared household with three others, and we're interested to see which of us is using the largest amount of our monthly internet quota. We're all happy to install the necessary software.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[NetLimiter Monitor](http://www.netlimiter.com/)** is perfect for what you have in mind. it will give you detailed usage statistics (even by application) per hour, day, week, year or any period you specify.

[image]

*NetLimiter Monitor is freeware.*

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of free network bandwidth monitoring programs out there. Here are two:

- **[AnalogX NetStat Live](http://www.analogx.com/contents/download/network/nsl.htm)**

  [image: AnalogX]
- **[NetWorx](http://www.softperfect.com/products/networx/)**

  [image: NetWorx system tray icon] [image: NetWorx system tray icon] [image: NetWorx Usage Report]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For Win 7, there are quite a few Sidebar Gadget who do just that. I can't recommend you any, because there's a lot of them.

Google them, and I'm sure you'll find the ones you like. I for example use this

[image]

There are more out there much more detailed ones.

Answer (score 0):

DU Meter is the best program I know for getting weekly/monthly totals, but it:

1. isn't free and
2. can only select network interfaces to monitor, but not local network/internet

... so probably no go for you :/

Answer (score 0):

Check out [CS Fire Monitor](http://www.pcwintech.com/cs-fire-monitor). It keeps detailed statistics in a database for future viewing, and it can also be checked remotely with it's "Remote View" feature. It can also monitor:

- CPU
- Drives
- Hardware
- Memory
- Processeses
- Services
- Software
- Tasks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[DU Meter](http://www.hageltech.com/dumeter/about) actually discriminates between Internet and LAN traffic since version 5.0, and it can create report (even email notifications) or simply stop all Internet connectivity on a computer that is over a preset monthly limit.

[image: DU Meter]

Comment: But is this free?  The question asked for free software.