# Monitor network traffic on PC's connected to router

Tags: networking, display, lan, traffic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Software for measuring internet traffic?](https://superuser.com/questions/75083/software-for-measuring-internet-traffic)

Hi!

Anyone know of an application for Windows or Mac that can monitor the amount of network traffic on the different computers connected to the same router? I want to find out which machine is hogging all the bandwidth on my LAN...

Thanks :D

Comment: similar suggestions here: http://superuser.com/questions/22569/monitor-all-and-any-internet-traffic-from-my-home-pc-what-should-i-use-closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[NetLimiter Monitor](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Network-Tools/Network-Monitoring/NetLimiter-Monitor.shtml)** will monitor the usage per machine (Windows only).

[image]

*NetLimiter Monitor is freeware.*

However, this software has to be installed on each computer. If you want to collect usage statistics for the entire network on one computer, you will have to setup this computer as a router and route all traffic through this computer (e.g. with **[Vyatta Community Edition](http://www.vyatta.org/)**). Or install a router compatible with **[DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index)**.  Not only can you monitor the traffic for each computer but you can also limit the bandwidth via traffic shaping.

Comment: I think he wants to do this from 1 computer, and see the traffic consumption from **all** machines.

Comment: yep, i gathered that much ... :)

Comment: Is this compatible with Vista and 7?

Comment: @Nathaniel - all versions of NetLimiter are compatible with Windows 2000 or higher, x86 & x64

Answer (score 1):

for network monitoring software, the most famous one is wireshark,it is free and can be used on multi-platform.Its decoding ability is the strongest in free network monitoring software.
If you have budget, I would like to recommend [Capsa](http://www.colasoft.com/capsa/?prid=05030005) for commercial usage under windows.Compared with wireshark, it is more visualize,and its flexible reporting is more suitable for company network administration.