# What is best lan network monitoring tool?

Tags: networking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Monitor all and any internet traffic from my home PC - what should I use?](https://superuser.com/questions/22569/monitor-all-and-any-internet-traffic-from-my-home-pc-what-should-i-use)

What is best lan network monitoring tool?

Comment: This question is better addressed on superuser.com

Comment: What exactly do you mean by monitoring?  Are you wanting to monitor the status of systems on your network or capture traffic?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/22569/monitor-all-and-any-internet-traffic-from-my-home-pc-what-should-i-use http://superuser.com/questions/103103/monitor-network-traffic-on-pcs-connected-to-router

Answer (score 3):

[Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) is flat out the best monitoring tool.

> Wireshark is very similar to tcpdump,
>   but it has a graphical front-end, and
>   many more information sorting and
>   filtering options. It allows the user
>   to see all traffic being passed over
>   the network (usually an Ethernet 
>   network but support is being added for
>   others) by putting the network
>   interface into promiscuous mode.

```
* Data can be captured "from the wire" from a live network connection or read from a file that recorded already-captured packets.
* Live data can be read from a number of types of network, including Ethernet, IEEE 802.11, PPP, and loopback.
* Captured network data can be browsed via a GUI, or via the terminal (command line) version of the utility, tshark.
* Captured files can be programmatically edited or converted via command-line switches to the "editcap" program.
* Data display can be refined using a display filter.
* Plug-ins can be created for dissecting new protocols.
```

From [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireshark).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can take a look at [Microsoft Network Monitor](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=983b941d-06cb-4658-b7f6-3088333d062f&displaylang=en) (netmon) if you work with Windows:

[image: MS netmon]