# Check which PC is using full network capacity

Tags: networking, software-rec, network-monitoring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Software for measuring internet traffic?](https://superuser.com/questions/75083/software-for-measuring-internet-traffic)

Once I had a program which would be able to see which PC in the network used the most (if not all) network capacity. Let's say one of the users is downloading, I'd like to know who it was.

Routing rules don't apply now here, but I'm just looking for that or similar application.

Anyone knows this application? (for Windows)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Software for measuring internet traffic?](http://superuser.com/questions/75083/software-for-measuring-internet-traffic) and/or [Monitor network traffic on PC's connected to router](http://superuser.com/questions/103103/monitor-network-traffic-on-pcs-connected-to-router)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the freeware [Colasoft Capsa](http://www.colasoft.com/) for that kind of monitoring.  Of course, to get the most benefit from it, you'll need to have it monitor a port that is connected to a switch port that has all LAN traffic mirrored to it, otherwise you'll only see a portion of the traffic.  But you can get a good smartswitch that provides mirroring for under $100 these days.