# Home solutions to measure internet traffic?

Tags: router, internet, traffic

What is the simplest solution to measure entire internet traffic at home? I have several computers connected to Internet via `D-Link DIR-615`.

Comment: @techie007 While software is one possible method, the user didn't specify that they wanted only a software solution. There are hardware solutions for this as well.

Answer (score 0):

While product recommendations are generally off-topic here, there are a couple types of solutions that you can use. Some are more practical than others for home use.

**Software Solutions**

- Dedicate one computer to run **software that tracks data usage** across your local network. One fantastic solution for this is [NetLimiter Monitor](http://www.netlimiter.com/). It can track just on local client, or traffic within your local network. [Paessler](http://www.paessler.com/router_bandwidth_monitor) also makes freeware that can do similar tasks.

[image]

*A similar question was asked [here](https://superuser.com/questions/75083/software-for-measuring-internet-traffic), credit for this part of my answer goes to [Molly7244](https://superuser.com/a/75308/201262)*

- Routers typically have a built-in traffic monitoring log. While this typically isn't very comprehensive, you can find routers that have more robust traffic monitoring tools built-in.

---

**Hardware Solutions**

- Most hardware solutions will be geared towards corporate networks, and most of the time will simply be overkill in terms of features and way overpriced for a home application.
- Some hardware firewalls have built-in bandwidth monitoring. I have friends in IT who have recommended [Fortinet](http://www.fortinet.com/) appliances for QoS and bandwidth management.