# Network traffic analyzer ignores the Remote Play traffic

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, traffic, netsh

I've wanted to measure network traffic that flows between my PS3 & PS VITA while they are lock on the Remote Play function. I need that because I want to discover what min. network bandwidth should I have to run this smoothly through the WAN. I use the DU METER software that I found here: [LINK](https://superuser.com/questions/75083/software-for-measuring-internet-traffic). The configuration of my local network looks like this:

```
[PS VITA] >> [win 8.1 wlan HOSTEDNETWORK] << [PS3]
                         |
                      [W W W]
// all above is WIFI
// the measurement is set on the Virtual HOSTEDNETWORK card
```

**The problem is** that while devices are hooked on Remote Play on the `hostednetwork`, the DU meter shows about 3,4 kbps on Upload and Download speed.

But when it comes to watch a video on YT from the PS VITA itself (without using the remote play) the traffic readings on DU meter seems to be alright and rises up to the speed of my maximum network performance (~1200 kbps). Now why is that? Is the network flow analyzer monitors only specific ports? I tried few of them and results are the same

Comment: Is the `[win 8.1 wlan HOSTEDNETWORK]` a computer broadcasting a wifi network ?

Comment: Yes this is a Virtual WiFi created by: `netsh wlan set hostednetwork ssid=RemotePlay ... `, and it is linked with a shared WIFI card that is connected to the router.

Comment: Network Flow Analyzer probably only reports on traffic from the wifi out another interface. Since traffic isn't leaving the interface to go from the PS VITA to the PS3, it probably isn't seeing any of the traffic. Can you set the interface it monitors ?